# Blazor - Razor markup in c# class file

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor

I'm splitting code in a Blazor file into a .cs file but am having issues with leftover markup.

Example from https://blazor.radzen.com/dialog

Using the dialogue where the markup is mixed into the code:

```
async Task ShowInlineDialog()
{
 var result = await DialogService.OpenAsync("Simple Dialog", ds =>
    @<div>
        <p class="mb-4">Confirm Order ID <b>@orderID</b>?</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <RadzenButton Text="Ok" Click="() => ds.Close(true)" class="me-1" Style="width: 80px;" />
                <RadzenButton Text="Cancel" Click="() => ds.Close(false)" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" class="me-1" />
                <RadzenButton Text="Refresh" Click="(() => { orderID = 10249; ds.Refresh(); })" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light"  class="me-1 float-end" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>);

  console.Log($"Dialog result: {result}");
}
```

When attempting to move this snippet into the code file (.cs), the markup is failing.

Cursory searching has yield nothing, but my google-fu could be weak.

Any hints appreciated, thank you.

Comment: This is not really needed since the dialog service can return values so it's possible to turn the above into a blazor component and return the boolean value, but I'm still curious to see if there's a way to mix in markup in a class file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't put Razor markup in a C# class file.  It must be in a Razor file so the Razor compiler can compile it.

You can define markup blocks as `RenderFragments` like this:

```cs
@MyButtonRow

\\....

@code {

\\...

async Task ShowInlineDialog()
{
 var result = await DialogService.OpenAsync("Simple Dialog", MyDialogContent);

  Console.Log($"Dialog result: {result}");
}

private RenderFragment MyDialogContent => __builder => {
    <div>
        <p class="mb-4">Confirm Order ID <b>@orderID</b>?</p>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col">
                <RadzenButton Text="Ok" Click="() => ds.Close(true)" class="me-1" Style="width: 80px;" />
                <RadzenButton Text="Cancel" Click="() => ds.Close(false)" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light" class="me-1" />
                <RadzenButton Text="Refresh" Click="(() => { orderID = 10249; ds.Refresh(); })" ButtonStyle="ButtonStyle.Light"  class="me-1 float-end" />

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>);
};

}
```

Comment: This is all good, but I wonder, OP has DialogService variable available and calls its OpenAsync. How do you pass DialogService so it is recognised in the RenderFragment. You just have ds variable standing for DialogService in your answer.

Comment: The primary answer was NO you can't.  I added the code block to simply demonstrate how you can encapsulate markup in properties.

Comment: That's fine. I might ask my question then as a new question.

Comment: Ask away.   I've just found the DialogService on the Radzen site, and can see how it's constructed, so can probably ask your question.  I've also updated this answer which may answer your question.